# PHP array in array - DXF script

Tags: php, dxf

I found a php script to write DXF file based on coordinates of polygon. IT works on the test file with this code (for polygon):

```
$d->append(new DxfPolyLine(array('points'=>array(array(1, 1),
                                        array(20, 10), 
                                        array(20, 20), 
                                        array(1, 15)),
                            'lineType'=>'DASHED',
//                          'layer' => 'DXFWRITER',
                            'flag' => 0
                            //'width' => 1,
                            //'color'=>1
                            )
));
```

The DXF file result is like this:

```
VERTEX
8
0
6
DASHED
10
20.000
20
20.000
0
VERTEX
8
0
6
DASHED
10
1.000
20
15.000
0
```

A lot of vertex's inside a polyline.
Now I am trying to insert my own coordinates. I have the coordinates but how can I write an array in that array?
I have this: `$g=array_merge($g,array(array($coord[$z]*3.527785, $coord[$z+1]*3.527785)));`
With this code the result is:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -133.92170714209 [1] => -41.834100838885 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => -135.19600658422 [1] => -44.558002415365 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => -173.40700872797 [1] => -25.465001344078 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => -211.44500829533 [1] => -6.4740001788315 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => -209.93490817601 [1] => -3.255100166471 ) [5] => 
Array ( [0] => -190.0770099388 [1] => -13.202000524885 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => -171.92300716209 [1] => -22.296000898041 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => -172.13500940166 [1] => -22.749000947663 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => -171.12900859213 [1] => -23.251001225378 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => -152.49300807866 [1] => -32.559001622754 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => -133.92170714209 [1] => -41.834100838885 ) )
```

So far so good. It respects the format from example. But in the DXF file does write only 1 (from array number).
If I change the code in

```
$d->append(new DxfPolyLine(array('points'=>array($g[3]),
```

with array[3] - it does write the coordinates in DXF file. Is there a way to make php to read all arrays from an array? I've tried with foreach but it doesn't work. PHP gives an error for not closing the ).
The source code is here:
https://github.com/digitalfotografen/DXFwriter
With $g[3] I have the coordinates from array[3] in DXF file:

```
VERTEX
8
0
6
CONTINUOUS
10
-211.445
20
-6.474
0
```

If I put $g simple I have:

```
VERTEX
8
0
6
CONTINUOUS
10
1.000
20
1.000
30
1.000
40
1.000
50
1.000
60
1.000
70
1.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the `$g` array based on your dump. Does this outputs the desired DXF file?

```
$g = [[-133.92170714209, -41.834100838885],
      [-135.19600658422, -44.558002415365],
      [-173.40700872797, -25.465001344078],
      [-211.44500829533, -6.4740001788315],
      [-209.93490817601, -3.255100166471 ], 
      [-190.0770099388 , -13.202000524885],
      [-171.92300716209, -22.296000898041],
      [-172.13500940166, -22.749000947663],
      [-171.12900859213, -23.251001225378],
      [-152.49300807866, -32.559001622754],
      [-133.92170714209, -41.834100838885]
     ];
$d->append(new DxfPolyLine(['points' => $g]));
```

regarding building the array, you could do something like this:

```
for ($z = 0;  $z < $numar; $z+=2) {
   $g[] = [$coord[$z]*3.527785,$coord[$z+1]*3.527785];
}
```

Comment: It looks ok. I will try this solution. I don't know if the file is ok and can be oppened in CAD software.

Comment: It does work. But how can I make an array inside a for? Those coordinates are parsed from a SVG file. for ($z=0;$z<$numar;$z+=2)
  {
   //echo $coord[$z]*3.527785.",".$coord[$z+1]*3.527785."<br>";
   $g=$g.[$coord[$z]*3.527785,$coord[$z+1]*3.527785];
   
  }

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tryied with array_merge, didn't work. Forgot about $g[].

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting's a bit screwy, but looking at the dumped array-data I see a single array who's values are arrays, that have 2 float values each. Note that Array[0] and Array[10] have the same values which may or may not be a problem for the lib.

Also, what's with the asterisks in the `$d->append...` logic?

> Is there a way to make php to read all arrays from an array?

Yes, but PHP will impose some restrictions depending on the nature of the keys and values. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for more specific info as to how PHP treats arrays.

> I've tried with foreach but it doesn't work. PHP gives an error for not closing the ).

Can you post the failing code please? What you describe is simply a formatting / syntax error and nothing to do with the data itself.

Comment: The asterisks was for bolding text here. Ignore it please. Array 0 and array[10] are the same but it's no problem. They represent coordinates of a polyline in dxf. So it is ok. Each array has an array with coordinatest X and Y of a polygon wich shoud be a VERTEX in dxf file. For example Array[0] has 2 Arrays: array[0] and Array[1] - coordinates X and Y. Array[10] has 2 Arrays, [0] and [1], X and Y. I don't know how to make php to read the arrays with coordinates. I have succeded only by inserting the number of array wich returns the coordinates. If I put there Array[5] php can extract X and Y